# Cannot iterate multiple times on GroupByKey transformation output

Tags: apache-beam

The output of Apache-Beam GroupByKey.create() transformation is PCollection< KV< K,Iterable< V>>>.

When I am trying to iterate this Iterable more than once, **using SparkRunner**, I get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ValueIterator can't be iterated more than once,otherwise there could be data lost
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.GroupNonMergingWindowsFunctions$GroupByKeyIterator$ValueIterator.iterator(GroupNonMergingWindowsFunctions.java:163)
    at java.lang.Iterable.spliterator(Iterable.java:101)
```

Looking inside code of ValueIterator shows that ValueIterator forbid to create more than one iterator for this Itrable< V>.

Why can't I create multiple iterators from this Iterable? which data can be lost?

Code example:

```
import com.google.common.base.MoreObjects;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.*;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class Main implements Serializable {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Main().runPipeline(args);
    }

    private void runPipeline(String[] args) {

        PipelineOptions options =
                PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create();
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        pipeline
                .apply(Create.of(
                        "trader1,10.0",
                        "trader1,20.0",
                        "trader1,5.0",
                        "trader2,7.0",
                        "trader2,30.0",
                        "trader2,2.0",
                        "trader3,10.0"))
                .apply(ParDo.of(extractKey()))
                .apply(GroupByKey.<String, Trade>create())
                .apply(ParDo.of(calculateMax()))
                .apply(ParDo.of(calculateMin()))
                .apply(ToString.elements())
                .apply(TextIO.write().to("output.txt"));

        pipeline.run();
    }

    private static DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<Trade>>, KV<String, IterableAndCalculationWrapper>> calculateMax() {
        return new DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<Trade>>, KV<String, IterableAndCalculationWrapper>>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(@Element KV<String, Iterable<Trade>> element, ProcessContext context) {
                String key = element.getKey();
                Iterable<Trade> iterable = element.getValue();
                Double max = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).mapToDouble(Trade::getTransactionAmount).max().getAsDouble();

                // Un-commenting this line throws exception:
                //Double min = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).mapToDouble(Trade::getTransactionAmount).min().getAsDouble();

                Map<String, Double> caclulated = new HashMap<>();
                caclulated.put("max", max);
                context.output(KV.of(key, new IterableAndCalculationWrapper(iterable, caclulated)));
            }

        };
    }

    private static DoFn<KV<String, IterableAndCalculationWrapper>, KV<String, IterableAndCalculationWrapper>> calculateMin() {
        return new DoFn<KV<String, IterableAndCalculationWrapper>, KV<String, IterableAndCalculationWrapper>>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(@Element KV<String, IterableAndCalculationWrapper> element, ProcessContext context) {
                String key = element.getKey();
                IterableAndCalculationWrapper iterableAndCalculationWrapper = element.getValue();
                Iterable<Trade> iterable = iterableAndCalculationWrapper.getIterable();

                // This line throws exception:
                Double min = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).mapToDouble(Trade::getTransactionAmount).min().getAsDouble();

                iterableAndCalculationWrapper.getMap().put("min", min);
                context.output(KV.of(key, iterableAndCalculationWrapper));
            }
        };
    }


    public static DoFn<String, KV<String, Trade>> extractKey() {
        return new DoFn<String, KV<String, Trade>>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(@Element String element, ProcessContext context) {
                String[] row = element.split(",");
                Trade trade = new Trade(row[0], Double.valueOf(row[1]));
                context.output(KV.of(trade.traderId, trade));
            }
        };
    }

    private static class IterableAndCalculationWrapper implements Serializable {
        private Iterable<Trade> iterable;
        private Map<String, Double> map;

        public IterableAndCalculationWrapper(Iterable<Trade> iterable, Map<String, Double> map) {
            this.iterable = iterable;
            this.map = map;
        }

        public Iterable<Trade> getIterable() {
            return iterable;
        }

        public void setIterable(Iterable<Trade> iterable) {
            this.iterable = iterable;
        }

        public Map<String, Double> getMap() {
            return map;
        }

        public void setMap(Map<String, Double> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                    .add("iterable", iterable)
                    .add("map", map)
                    .toString();
        }
    }

    private static class Trade implements Serializable {
        private String traderId;
        private Double transactionAmount;

        public Trade(String traderId, Double transactionAmount) {
            this.traderId = traderId;
            this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
        }

        public String getTraderId() {
            return traderId;
        }

        public void setTraderId(String traderId) {
            this.traderId = traderId;
        }

        public Double getTransactionAmount() {
            return transactionAmount;
        }

        public void setTransactionAmount(Double transactionAmount) {
            this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                    .add("traderId", traderId)
                    .add("transactionAmount", transactionAmount)
                    .toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you do that in another `.apply()` function using the same PCollection ?

Comment: I want to get many values in one transformation: iterating the Iterable to get the max/min/ and many more calculations.

Comment: I tried now with another `.apply`: same exception.  
Debugging shows that when I pass this Iterable as is (KV< K, Iterable< V>>) from one ParDo transformation to another - the Iterable< V> is actually the same Object in both transformations. 
Therefore - even iterating it in different transformations cannot be done.

Does this means that the only way to iterate **grouped elements** can be done by FlatMap this iterable to elements and group it again (to get new Iterable of same elements)?

Comment: Don't pass the PCollection from one ParDo to another. Instead, do multiple ParDo with the same PCollection. Elements in ParDo are imutable, so the Iterable values won't already be processed. Should you provide code samples, I would be able to help you.

Comment: I added now the code to the question. Can you explain more what do you mean by 'multiple ParDo with the same PCollection'? I already tried to branch the pipeline and I saw that the same Iterable is passed to both branched transformations, meaning - one of them will fail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store intermediate results of your pipeline in PCollections.

```
PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<Trade>>> tmpCollection = 
    pipeline.apply(Create.of(
            "trader1,10.0",
            "trader1,20.0",
            "trader1,5.0",
            "trader2,7.0",
            "trader2,30.0",
            "trader2,2.0",
            "trader3,10.0"))
    .apply(ParDo.of(extractKey()))
    .apply(GroupByKey.<String, Trade>create());


PCollection<KV<String, IterableAndCalculationWrapper>> collectionMax = tmpCollection.apply(ParDo.of(calculateMax()));
PCollection<KV<String, IterableAndCalculationWrapper>> collectionMin = tmpCollection.apply(ParDo.of(calculateMin()));
```

Doing this will allow you to iterate once for the calculateMax, and once for the calculateMin. Then you will need to handle both collection separately until you merge them.

Comment: Thanx! that works.     But - how can I do another iteration on those grouped elements later in pipeline (for another calculation or some other use....) without loosing the calculated fields in IterableAndCalculationWrapper?

Comment: @NoamGershi What you can do is use the _tmpCollection_ as a sideInput of another *ParDo* function to update or merge the results of *IterableAndCalculationWrapper*